# button control prompts null reference exception when i use it within sub method in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, nullreferenceexception

i have a button when i click it, it should switch the language or culture of the application, the problem is that i alawys get null referece exception for the button
here is my vb code

```
 Protected Overrides Sub InitializeCulture()

    If ddlLanguages2.InnerText.ToString.Trim.Equals(("English").ToString.Trim) Then
        ddlLanguages2.InnerText = "عربي"
        Dim selectedLanguage As String = "en-us"
        UICulture = "en-us"
        Culture = "en-us"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New _
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)

    ElseIf ddlLanguages2.InnerText.ToString.Trim.Equals(("عربي").ToString.Trim) Then
        ddlLanguages2.InnerText = "English"
        Dim selectedLanguage As String =
           "ar-kw"
        UICulture = "ar-kw"
        Culture = "ar-kw"
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage)
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = New _
            CultureInfo(selectedLanguage)

    End If
    MyBase.InitializeCulture()
End Sub



Protected Sub ddlLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    InitializeCulture()

End Sub
```

it stops when it reaches the the first "if" statement,by the way, any control does't work within the InitializeCulture

```
  <button id="ddlLanguages2" style="margin-top: 5px" runat="server" 
  onserverclick="ddlLanguages_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                    عربي
                        </button>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Enable CLR Exceptions, you will get he exact line where the code is breaking. Or post the stack trace. It will help

Comment: i know where it breaks , in the first if statement If ddlLanguages2.InnerText.ToString.Trim.Equals(("English").ToString.Trim) Then

Comment: check if the item exists in the list like ddlLanguages2.Items.FindByText

Comment: i dont have a list, i just forgot to change the name to proper one

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)